# VBA Excel - Uso de símbolo comodín en una variable

Tags: excel, vba

mediante una macro en vba, quiero abrir un fichero excel que guardan cada día en el sharepoint de la empresa con un nombre diferente.

El nombre del fichero tiene la siguiente estructura: fechayhorageneracion_bdventa_códigonumericoaleatorio.xlsx

El problema es que no puedo saber por adelantado la hora de generación ni el código numérico aleatorio.
Estaba utilizando una variable en la que quería utilizar el comodín * pero no me funciona

El código sería:

```
Sub ejemplo()

Dim FicheroOrigen As String
Dim DiaActual As String
Dim MesActual As String
Dim AñoActual As String

DiaActual = String(2 - Len(Day(Date)), "0") & Day(Date)
MesActual = String(2 - Len(Month(Date)), "0") & Month(Date)
AñoActual = Year(Date)

FicheroOrigen = "https://XXXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX/Shared Documents/General/Datos/" & AñoActual & "-" & MesActual & "-" & DiaActual & "*.xlsx"
```

La macro intenta abrir el fichero 2021-05-17*.xlsx (en el caso que se ejecute en el día de hoy) y no el fichero 2021-05-17T09_37_30+00_00 - BDVentas_34_6905098401247893371.xlsx

Gracias

Comment: *no puedo saber por adelantado la hora de generación ni el código numérico aleatorio* Entonces no puedes hacer lo que quieres de manera directa. Lo que no sé es si quizás podrías hacer un bucle que pasee por todos los archivos y entonces seleccione el más apropiado según esos parámetros.

Comment: Si es un fichero por día te recomiendo hacer lo que comenta Esei. Un bucle que recorra todos los ficheros y compruebe si en el nombre viene la fecha de ese día. Si encuentra un fichero que contenga esos datos en su nombre será el momento de tomar el nombre completo y montar tu string con la ruta completa.

Answer (score 3):

Quizás sea descabellado o no sea loq ue buscas, pero sería una opción

Si tienes acceso al código que genera el fichero con la fecha y el código aleatorio

Se me ocurre que podrías crear un duplicado con el nombre del fichero generado y almacenar éste nombre en un diccionario. En los diccionarios guardas los datos con (clave, valor), por lo que podrías almacenar el nombre de los ficheros por el la fecha en que se generó. Si solo se guarda un fichero diario, no habrá problemas de repeticion de la calve, pues ésta no puede estar repetida.

Clave: 2021-05-17
valor: 2021-05-17T09_37_30+00_00 - BDVentas_34_6905098401247893371.xlsx

Luego para abrir los ficheros solo tendrías que llamarlos por su clave, sin preocuparte por su nombre real.

Para crear y gestionar un diccionario:

```
 'Lo declaramos
 Dim Clave As Variant, nombreFichero() As Variant
 Set listaFicheros = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

 'Añadimos los elementos comenzando en la fila 2, la 1 para el nombre de las columnas
 i = 2

 'Creamos un bucle que en éste caso actuaría sobre la columna A
 Do While IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) = False 
     'Toma la Clave en la variable Fecha
     Fecha = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value        
     'Coprueba si la clave está repetida
     If ListaFicheros.Exists(Fecha) = True Then
        MsgBox ("La clave " & Fecha & " ya ha sido usada")
     Else
         'Agrega los nombres de los ficheros de la columna B
         ReDim nombreFichero(i - 1, 2)
         nombreFichero(i - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value 'Nombre real del Fichero
         'nombreFichero(i - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value 'Si quisieras usar otra columna de datos
         listaFicheros.Add Fecha, nombreFichero
    End If
 i = i + 1
 Loop
```

para acceder a los elementos del diccionario, los nombres de los ficheros, los buscaríamos con un bucle dándole la clave a buscar, o sea, la Fecha en que fue creado el fichero

```
For Each Clave In listaFicheros.Keys
    With listaFicheros(Clave) 
        fichero = .nombreFichero
    End With
Next key
```

Para ir agregando los nombres con su clave, podrías hacer una llamada a la función antes de intentar abrir el fichero