# Abrir TXT con parte del nombre fija

Tags: excel, vba

Actualmente he diseñado el siguiente código para abrir un archivo txt de forma automática.

Código:

```
Sub AbrirTXT()
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Apagar el parpadeo de pantalla
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Apagar Alertas
       Dim X As Variant
       X = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt, Add-in Files (*.txt), *.txt", 2, _
           "Abrir TXT", , True)
       For Y = 1 To UBound(X)
           Workbooks.Open X(Y)
       Next
End Sub
```

La cuestión es que quiero lograr dos cosas. Que se abra solo sin tener que seleccionar yo el archivo y que coja el que contiene una cadena de texto. Por ejemplo mi archivo txt es: **20210524122044_STIL_2_2GM809039.txt**

La parte **20210524122044** cambia pero **_STIL_2_2GM809039** siempre es igual. Así que me gustaría que abriese de forma automática el txt más reciente que tiene la cadena **_STIL_2_2GM809039**

Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Tendrás que hacer una macro que haga un bucle con todos los nombres de los archivos y seleccione el que cumple el parámetro que mencionas. Lo de *más reciente* no tengo claro cómo puedes implementarlo. https://blog.open-office.es/basic/recorrer-el-contenido-de-una-carpeta-con-dir

Comment: Entiendo. Voy a intentar hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: Aunque no te sirva de respuesta, pues no es exactamente lo que pides, te puede ayudar a darle un nuevo punto de vista. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452609/vba-excel-uso-de-s%c3%admbolo-comod%c3%adn-en-una-variable/454406#454406. Es mi respuesta a esa pregunta, y trataría de almacenar en un diccionario el nombre del fichero que se va generando automáticamente por la clave fecha y luego abrirlo por esa clave. En tu caso veo que la parte que cambia, lleva la fecha 20210524, por lo que tendrías que almacenar esa parte como clave, y el nombre completo como valor

Comment: Para sacar la fecha de modificación de un fichero tendrás utilizar FileSystemObject y la propiedad DateLastModified. Tendrás que recorrer la carpeta, revisar la fecha del fichero y si es más reciente que la última fecha revisada guardas en variables el nombre y la ruta. Así, una vez compruebes todos los ficheros, tendras almacenadas en tus variables el nombre y la ruta del fichero más reciente para poder hacer con él lo que quieras.

Comment: Utilizando Dir(Ruta & "Cadena fija") entre los comodines de * debería valer, a menos que tengas distintos ficheros con esa cadena.